# Use the value of an input variable as an object property

Tags: jsf, object, el

I have an array of objects and I want to display the output of an object property in outputText. The property is given by a variable. How I can do?

```
<h:outputText    id="cole14" value="#{Bean.ocupacion[0].} #{Bean.columna}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use a string at runtime to determine which property to display.  Try `#{Bean.ocupacion[0][Bean.columna]}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The result is perfect. I'm new in stackoverflow and I have no privilege to vote your answer but when I can I will.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
<h:outputText    id="cole14" value="#{Bean.ocupacion[0].columna}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, columna is not a property of the object.
What I need is the result of Bean.columna for use as the name of the object property

Comment: Bean.columna is independent of the object, so you want to display only the variable, so how could you display an object without expliciting its property ?

Comment: ok thanks for your interest in answering the question.
That's my problem, I need to use the value of the variable as the name of the object property.